# A term for a config dir that starts with a dot under home dir?

Tags: linux, configuration, path, installation

It is a common practice to create a local dir for your application on the user's machine under their $HOME, i.e. `~/.myapp/` and then put some configs inside. So the question is: is there a term for such a "dot-started config-dir under user's home"?

Answer (score 0):

No, the most recommendable is make the folder for example with

1 ) mkdir -p $HOME/.config/myapp
2 ) mkdir -p ~/.config/myapp

That is the default path for storage configs, but some developers just use ~/.myapp or $HOME/.myapp

If you wanna see the system variables (Under GNU/Linux) for example, open a terminal , and write $ when appears, press tab twice